# 3DSv2 always returns Status=OK even when attempting to force 3D-Secure

Tags: php, curl, opayo, 3d-secure

I am attempting to get 3DSv2 set up, and am currently in a **test** environment.

**Client URL (cURL)**

```
$paymentUrl = 'https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspdirect-register.vsp';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $paymentUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

$curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
$response = generateResponseArray($curlResponse);
var_dump($response);

function generateResponseArray($response)
{
    $output = [];

    $tempArray = explode(chr(10), $response);
    foreach ($tempArray as $row) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $row, 2);
        $output[$key] = trim($value);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Included in my `$postData` are the following items:

```
Apply3DSecure=1 // Force 3DS Challenge
CardNumber=4929000005559 // VERes = N
```

**Response**

```
array(15) {
  ["VPSProtocol"]=>
  string(4) "4.00"
  ["Status"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["StatusDetail"]=>
  string(40) "0000 : The Authorisation was Successful."
  ["VPSTxId"]=>
  string(38) "{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
  ["SecurityKey"]=>
  string(10) "XXXXXXXXXX"
  ["TxAuthNo"]=>
  string(7) "XXXXXXX"
  ["AVSCV2"]=>
  string(24) "SECURITY CODE MATCH ONLY"
  ["AddressResult"]=>
  string(10) "NOTMATCHED"
  ["PostCodeResult"]=>
  string(10) "NOTMATCHED"
  ["CV2Result"]=>
  string(7) "MATCHED"
  ["3DSecureStatus"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["CAVV"]=>
  string(28) "TnVqajA3TjdxTjhrRGFIMWROTzI="
  ["DeclineCode"]=>
  string(2) "00"
  ["ExpiryDate"]=>
  string(4) "0225"
  ["BankAuthCode"]=>
  string(6) "999777"
}
```

Shouldn't my status be coming back as `3DAUTH` at this point? I need to continue building our 3D-Secure system, but this payment shouldn't have an `OK` status here.

We have a rule set up in Sage Pay to require 3D-Secure on payments over 500 GBP. This one is.

This is the document I am working from: [Direct Integration and Protocol 4 Guidelines](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/library/document/directintegrationandprotocol4guidelinespdf)

Comment: To whoever voted to close this, the Sage Pay support website directly links me to Stack Overflow for this sort of query: https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/support-forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Sagepay Test environment, you need to send through a valid test card number (I use `4462 0000 000 0003`), and **crucially** the `CardHolder` set to `CHALLENGE`.

If you don't do this, the transaction will still go through 3-D Secure, but it will be *frictionless* (i.e the user won't see any iframes etc etc). You'll still get liability shift for frictionless transactions.

Also note you can use the `CardHolder` field to test other scenarios. Here is a complete list:

- `SUCCESSFUL` - Simulate a frictionless flow where authentication is successful
- `NOTAUTH` - Simulate a frictionless flow where authentication is NOT successful
- `CHALLENGE` - Simulate a challenge flow, where the cardholder will be re-directed to the ACS to enter two-factor authentication. A CReq, VPSTxId, ACSURL and StatusDetail will also be returned.
  Once you re-direct to the ACSURL, entering the correct password (Text = `challenge`) on the site will simulate a successful authentication, entering any other password will simulate an un-successful authentication.
- `PROOFATTEMPT` - Simulate the cardholder attempting to authenticate themselves, but the process did not complete. A CAVV is returned and this is treated as being successfully authenticated.
- `NOTENROLLED` - Simulate the card not being enrolled in the 3D-Secure scheme.
- `TECHNICALDIFFICULTIES` - Simulate 3D-Secure authentication being unable to complete. No authentication occurred.
- `STATUS201DS` - Simulate fallback to 3DSv1. You will receive a PAReq, MD, ACSURL and StatusDetail
- `ERROR` - Simulate an error condition where 3D-Authentication cannot be performed due to data errors or service unavailability in one of the parties involved in the check.